# Distance from point to line through Archimedean solid?

Tags: calculus

I have a problem I am trying to solve, but I am not having very much luck.

This is the question:

> The Archimedean solids are 13 semi-regular polyhedrons whose faces are
>   regular polygons of two or more types and whose vertices, or corners,
>   are all alike. An example of an Archimedean solid is the truncated
>   octahedron which is obtained from a regular octahedron by slicing off
>   the “same amount” from each corner. Suppose the truncated octahedron
>   has vertices $A(−1, 3, 0), B(−1, 1, −1), C(−3, −1, 0) \space and \space D(−3, 1, 0)$
>
> What is the distance of C to the line through A and B? And what is the
>   distance between the line through A, B and the line through C, D?

If anyone could give me a hand, I would be very grateful.

Thanks
Corey :)

Comment: Points A,B are in plane P and points C,D are in a plane Q . Planes P and Q are parallel, displaced by 2 units. Basically the distances between skew lines, calculation by vectors in 3D using dot and cross products.

Comment: Hey, Thanks heaps for that, I think I may have it. Does this sound right? $$2.6833$$?

Comment: Is this is an answer for first part or the second ? You may like to show how you got what you got.